# Search, match and replace 1st column with a value using sed

Tags: sed

I would like to get some advice using sed on how to replace value1 on first column that matches with value2:

```
value1 = 9999
value2 = 02a-ResetFlag.sh

Data File
----------------------------------
0500 * * 1 ( 02-StartFix.sh)

1850 * * 1 ( 02a-ResetFlag.sh)

2000 * * 1 ( 03-StopFix.sh)

2005 * * 1 ( 04-DssEOD.sh)

Expected output:
-----------------------------------
0500 * * 1 ( 02-StartFix.sh)

9999 * * 1 ( 02a-ResetFlag.sh)

2000 * * 1 ( 03-StopFix.sh)

2005 * * 1 ( 04-DssEOD.sh)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If the content of file `data` is

```
0500 * * 1 ( 02-StartFix.sh)
1850 * * 1 ( 02a-ResetFlag.sh)
2000 * * 1 ( 03-StopFix.sh)
2005 * * 1 ( 04-DssEOD.sh)
```

then

```
sed -i -r '/02a-ResetFlag.sh/{s/^([0-9]+)(.*)$/9999\2/g}' data
```

will modify the file `data` to

```
0500 * * 1 ( 02-StartFix.sh)
9999 * * 1 ( 02a-ResetFlag.sh)
2000 * * 1 ( 03-StopFix.sh)
2005 * * 1 ( 04-DssEOD.sh)
```

tested in `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the search pattern is at the end of the line (`$` is end of line marker) and the replacement string is at start of file-:

```
sed '/02a-ResetFlag.sh)$/ s/^1850/9999/'  data-file
```